# CS50.h segmentation fault if memory is not allocated to string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, cs50, c-strings

While working on a CS50 problem set (substitution), I encountered a segmentation fault when running the code. After some searching I found out that assigning memory (malloc) to string "output" fixes the issue. However I wanted to understand why assigning memory is necessary here?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

code extract: -please note i am using the cs50.h library

```
string cipher(string input, string key) {

    string output=malloc(strlen(input)+1);

    for (int i=0, len = strlen(input); i<len; i++) {
        if(isalpha(input[i]) != 0) {

                output[i] = substitute(input[i], key);
            }

        else {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }

    return output;
    free(output);
}
```

Comment: Allocating memory is necessary here for the same reason it is necessary for every buffer not yet allocated. And BTW, you want to have your `return` statement **after** your `free` statement, not before it.

Comment: Be aware that there is no `string` type in C. `string` is just a misleading cs50 way to write `char *`.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for the quick reply. how come initialising `output` to `output = "A....."` still gives me a segmentation fault?

Comment: If you replace the call to `malloc` with `output = "A..."` your pointer points to a string literal which mustn't be modified. When you assign values to it via `output[i]=` this is illegal.

Comment: `return output; free(output);` This does not make any sense. 1: `free` is never reached as you jump out of the function just before it. 2: if you would free the memory, the caller wasn't allowed to use it anymore after you return.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I could know about CS50.h string, I came to know that

`string output`

is just declaring a character pointer named output. So what actually happens in your code is that until you explicitly declare the "strlen(input)+1" contiguous memory locations beloging to output only, they are essentially free locations for the program. Hence, your output pointer will contain only the character at the 0th index. The function returns what "output" actually is, a pointer. Some process within the program meanwhile may make use of all the other memory locations other than output[0], since they never belonged to output string. output only pointed to the first character of some string.

Bound checking in C, C++ is essentially done by the  programmer. output[i] for any arbitrary i will never give an error because it's a simple pointer arithmetic for the programmer, i.e. output[i] = *(output+i).
:)

Answer (score 0):

For starters this statement

```
free(output);
```

never gets the control because it is placed after the return statement

```
return output;
```

and moreover it does not make a sense. It is the caller of the function that is responsible to free the allocated memory.

You need to dynamically allocated memory because otherwise if you will declare a variable length array like

```
char output[strlen(input)+1];
```

then after exiting the function it will not be alive and an attempt to access the array outside the function results in undefined behavior.

That is if you will just write

```
string output;
```

that is equivalent to

```
char *output;
```

then the pointer output has indeterminate value because it was not initialized and neither memory was allocated where the source string will be copied.

You could change the source string `input` in place without creating one more array.

In this case it would be enough to write

```
    if(isalpha(input[i]) != 0) {

            input[i] = substitute(input[i], key);
        }
```

and then you could place the statement

```
return input;
```

Pay attention to that using the alias `string` for the type `char *` is a bad idea.

The function declaration if to rewrite it like

```
char * cipher(char *input, char *key);
```

is confusing. It is unclear whether the strings input and key are being changed within the function or not.

If you want that the function returns a new string build from the source string then the function declaration should look like

```
char * cipher(const char *input, const char *key);
```

Thus answering your question

> However I wanted to understand why assigning memory is necessary here?

if you want to create a new string from the source string pointed to by the pointer `input` then it is evident that you need to allocate a new character array where elements of the source string will be copied.

Otherwise if you want to change the source string in place then there is no need to create one more array.